# Microsoft ADCS: Unable to register a new Application Policy

Tags: active-directory, x509certificate, pki

I need to create a new, custom Application Policy and assign it to a certificate template.  I am logged in as an account which has Full Control on the **OID** container underneath the **Public Key Services** container in AD.

If I try to create the custom Application Policy via the Certificate Templates snap-in, I am receiving *windows could not save the new application policy name. Insufficient access rights to perform the operation*.

I also tried [Register-ObjectIdentifier](https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/pspki/Register-ObjectIdentifier/) Powershell Commandlet ([Source](https://github.com/PKISolutions/PSPKI/blob/master/PSPKI/Client/Register-ObjectIdentifier.ps1)). This returns:
*Exception calling "Register" with "6" argument(s): "Access is denied"*

There is very little documentation on this from Microsoft themselves, but according to Vadims Podans, as long as you have permissions to write to the **OID** container in AD, you should be able to do this.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You have to use `-UseActiveDirectory` switch. If this switch is not specified, then OID is registered locally. For local registration, you must have local administrator permissions and run in elevated shell.

Comment: @Crypt32 - Thank you. Unfortunately, this was not the issue. Our Microsoft rep was able to replicate the issue. He created an account with full permissions to the Certificate Templates and OID containers in his lab forest & received the same error as I did. I will report back when the root cause is determined.

Comment: Did you try the `-UseActiveDirectory` switch? What cmdlet returns?

Comment: @Crypt32 - Oddly enough, I wasn't able to import the PKI Module as the local administrator user. It couldn't connect to nuget, which makes sense since this is a server on our intranet. I'm actually wondering how it imported under the first account I used.

Either way, the Cert Templates GUI should have let me do it given the permissions my template account has, so I'm still thinking this is an AD permissions issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue, and just figured out a solution. Make sure that you not only have full permissions on the OID container, but on all descendants as well. If you go to the properties of the OID container -> security -> advanced, then select your user group and "special permissions" you can edit it to apply to "this object and all descendants." After making that change, I was able to create the application.